# How to use IKScannerDeviceView in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, scanning, ikscannerdeviceview

How can I use IKScannerDeviceView to scan a document inside of my app?

I tried adding an IKScannerDeviceView into my view through IB and setting its delegate to my app delegate (which implements the IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate), but when I run the app I get a view with the buttons `Show Details` and `Scan`, and only `Show Details` is enabled and when I click it nothing happens.

I have a scanner plugged in and I can scan through Image Capture, but not through my app.

Does anybody have a good tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: Is the delegate method `-scannerDeviceView:didEncounterError:` ever called?

Comment: It does not.  I have an IKScannerDeviceView and I have its delegate set to my AppDelegate (for now) and the app delegate does implement `IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate`, however `-scannerDeviceView:didEncounterError:` never gets called, both with a scanner plugged in and without one plugged in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out how to use IKScannerDeviceView.

Your class must implement the following delegates:

```
IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate, ICScannerDeviceDelegate, ICDeviceBrowserDelegate
```

and you need to have an IKScannerDeviceView in your window, with its delegate set to the class implementing `IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate`

To start using it, you must create an `ICDeviceBrowser` like so:

```
    ICDeviceBrowser *mDeviceBrowser = [[ICDeviceBrowser alloc] init];
    mDeviceBrowser.delegate = self;
    mDeviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceLocationTypeMaskLocal|ICDeviceLocationTypeMaskRemote|ICDeviceTypeMaskScanner;
    [mDeviceBrowser start];
```

Then implement the delegate methods in a manner similar to this:

```
- (void)scannerDeviceDidBecomeAvailable:(ICScannerDevice*)scanner;
{
    [scanner requestOpenSession];
}
- (void)deviceBrowser:(ICDeviceBrowser*)browser didAddDevice:(ICDevice*)addedDevice moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    if ( (addedDevice.type & ICDeviceTypeMaskScanner) == ICDeviceTypeScanner )
    {
        [scannerView setScannerDevice:(ICScannerDevice*)addedDevice];
    }
}
-(void)didRemoveDevice:(ICDevice*)removedDevice
{
    [removedDevice requestCloseSession];
}
```

Then if all goes right, your IKScannerDeviceView will be able to interact with your scanner!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, my scanner will scan, but scannerDeviceView…didScan gets called with nil URL, fileData, and error.