# Using IKScannerDeviceView in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, iboutlet, ikscannerdeviceview

I'm trying to use an IKScannerDeviceView. I have it placed in a window and I have followed this example here:

[How to use IKScannerDeviceView in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326156/how-to-use-ikscannerdeviceview-in-cocoa)

But I'm missing something. I can't create an IBOutlet for the IKScannerDeviceView. When I try to ctrl-drag in to my IKScannerDeviceViewDelegate.h Xcode creates the following IBOutlet:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet IKScannerDeviceView *scannerView;
```

but then I get the following error on it:

Unknown type name 'IKScannerDeviceView'; did you mean 'ICScannerDevice'?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was linking to the correct frameworks:

```
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
#import <ImageCaptureCore/ImageCaptureCore.h>
```

I was missing the Quartz.framework